# Underline and change the color of the title in bclogo

Tags: beamer, bclogo

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

%------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------
\AtBeginSubsection[]{%
  \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]{Outline}
  \transsplitverticalout
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{bclogo}[arrondi=0.1, logo=\bcquestion, couleurBarre=Maroon] 
        {Question}
    Why
    $$r_e(\mathbf{T})\geq r(\mathbf{T}) \;?$$
  \end{bclogo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

After compilation I get

[image]

However I want to change the color of the word question and to underline it as the following picture shows

[image]

Comment: `$$...$$` should be avoided, so it would be better to use `\[r_e(\mathbf{T})\geq r(\mathbf{T}) \;?\]`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/35864.

Comment: @moewe I don't see what is the difference. I see the linked question so many times however I don't see that there exists a big difference.

Comment: In most cases there will indeed not be a visual difference. But there are situations where `$$...$$` will give different spacing than `\[...\]` (and people usually prefer the spacing `\[...\]` gives). `\[...\]` also works together with the `fleqn` option and provides for better placement of `\qedhere`. You are of course free to ignore the advice not to use `$$...$$`, but I think the comment has a place here to warn other people who might be more susceptible to the arguments in the linked answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as the answer by JPi using the `soul` package to underline the title, but using `bclogo` mechanism to customise the title globally

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{soul}
\setul{}{1.5pt}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\renewcommand\bcStyleTitre[1]{\vskip-0.5em\bfseries\color{Maroon}\ul{#1}\vskip0em}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{bclogo}[arrondi=0.1, logo=\bcquestion, couleurBarre=Maroon] 
        {Question}
    Why
    \[
        r_e(\mathbf{T})\geq r(\mathbf{T}) \;?
    \]
  \end{bclogo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to mount the word question a little up?

Comment: @Student Sure..

Comment: When I repace in you codes `\documentclass{beamer}` by `\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}` it compilates well. Is the reason that my winedit version is old? Thank you.

Comment: @Student Oh, right. This option is necessary for the maroon colour

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
      \usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}
         \usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
      %------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------
     \AtBeginSubsection[]{
       \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]{Outline}
     \transsplitverticalout
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
       \end{frame}
      }

   \usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{soul}

     \begin{document}
\setul{}{1.5pt}

       \begin{frame}{}
        \begin{bclogo}[arrondi=0.1, logo=\bcquestion, couleurBarre=Maroon] 
              {\textcolor{red}{\ul{Question}}}
          Why
         \[r_e(\mathbf{T})\geq r(\mathbf{T}) \;?\]
          \end{bclogo}
        \end{frame}

     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is possible to takethe  horizontal line thickness like the vertical line? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I just changed the code.

Comment: I mean the thick of the line which underlines the word question is equal to the thick of the vertical line. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, did that..

Comment: Please your codes doen't compilate. Is there a problem?

Comment: @Student "Does not compile" is not a very useful statement. The code compiles just fine for me.

Comment: I get the message: `("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\sansmathaccent\ot1mathkerncmss.fd")
! Use of \@iminipage doesn't match its definition.
\beamer@ifnextcharospec #1#2->\def \reserved@a {
                                                #1}\def \reserved@b {#2}\fut...
l.24         \end{frame}
                        
?`