# Different colors of the title in bclogo

Tags: beamer, bclogo

Thanks to the following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466225/underline-and-change-the-color-of-the-title-in-bclogo),

```
         \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

     \usepackage{soul}
     \setul{}{1.5pt}

       \usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
       \renewcommand\bcStyleTitre[1]{\vskip- 
     0.8em\bfseries\color{Maroon}\ul{#1}\vskip0em}

       \begin{document}

       \begin{frame}
      \begin{bclogo}[arrondi=0.1, logo=\bcquestion, couleurBarre=Maroon]
      {Question}
        Why
           \[
          r_e(\mathbf{T})\geq r(\mathbf{T}) \;?
        \]
       \end{bclogo}

       \begin{bclogo}[couleur = gray!10, arrondi=0.1, logo=\bcattention, couleurBarre=Red]{Remark}
          It is important that...
        \end{bclogo}

        \begin{bclogo}[couleur = gray!30, arrondi =0.1 ,logo=\bcfleur]{Thanks!}
         $$
          $$
        \begin{center}
          \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{{Thank You for your attention !}}}
          \end{center}
           $$
            $$
          \end{bclogo}
       \end{frame}
         \end{document}
```

I get

[image]

However, I want to reduce the distance between the word 'why' and 'question'. Also I want to use different colors in the title as it is shown in the following picture

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use `renewcommand` where and how you need it?

Comment: @Johannes_B I cannot change the  colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off-topic comment:

Don't use `$$...$$` for equations -- the only thing worse than that is using it to face spacing!!!

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{soul}
\setul{}{1.5pt}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\colorlet{bctitle}{Maroon}

\renewcommand\bcStyleTitre[1]{\vskip-0.8em\bfseries\color{bctitle}\ul{#1}\vskip-0.7em}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{bclogo}[arrondi=0.1, logo=\bcquestion, couleurBarre=Maroon]
{Question}
Why
\[
r_e(\mathbf{T})\geq r(\mathbf{T}) \;?
\]
\end{bclogo}

{
\colorlet{bctitle}{red}
\begin{bclogo}[couleur = gray!10, arrondi=0.1, logo=\bcattention, couleurBarre=Red]{Remark}
It is important that...
\end{bclogo}
}

{
\colorlet{bctitle}{blue}
\begin{bclogo}[couleur = gray!30, arrondi =0.1 ,logo=\bcfleur]{Thanks!}
\bigskip
\begin{center}
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{{Thank You for your attention !}}}
\end{center}
\bigskip
\end{bclogo}

}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]